# Почему файл node_modules/rxjs/operator/delay.js не билдится?

Tags: angular2, typescript, npm

Собственно не могу понять, почему этот файл отсутствует? В консоль браузера вываливается соответствующая ошибка, когда я начинаю использовать rxjs:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/operator/delay.js
```

он и правда отсутствует. Однако delay.d.ts на месте. Стартую командой npm start, всё приложение собирается корректно кроме файла delay.js

Когда я вручную пробую скомпилировать, получаю ошибку:

```
../Observable.d.ts(68,60): error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Значит ли это, что ошибка в скаченном мною с гитхаба Angular2? или стоит искать другую проблему?

Comment: Какая у вас версия rc?

Comment: Простите. Речь идет о версии релиза? Или о чём?) Как мне узнать то, что вы спрашиваете?

Comment: я скачал quickstart-master, взял от туда папку rxjs и подменил в её в своём текущем проекте в папку модули и всё заработало. Может быть это можно было сделать как-то более технично. Сравнив версии и сделать апдейт. Я пробовал сначала сделать npm update, но это не дало нужного результата.

Comment: большинство js библиотек /фреймворков работают через npm

Comment: npm это менеджер пакетов ( [windows](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows) , [linux](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install))

Comment: npm настраивается через файл package.json. В Вашем проекте должен быть package.json. И вот в нём "rxjs": "5.0.1", где -  "5.0.1" это Ваша версия